# Which one is faster Color Filtering or use different drawables in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, colorfilter

i'm using icons on recyclerview row items.And i'm changing icon's colors with *Color Filter* option in android but i'm wondering which one is *faster* and *better*?

- different colored drawables
- (run-time) color filter on white
  drawable icon

I already use color filtering on white drawable but it sometimes does not appear in list row till refresh recyclerview so i just think about to use different drawables.
thank you for your interest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say, but I would say that changing the drawable is faster, and this is why I think this:

- in order to filter a image the system has to read each pixel from RAM, transform each RGB component in order to add the tint (it's not as simple as adding +3 to the intensity of each pixel), and then write each pixel
- changing the drawable implies reading from the flash memory and load it into ram

The thing is that flash storage on mobile devices is pretty fast too these days so I consider it's faster to load than tint images.

BUT it depends on how you create the layout. If you load a image the Android system will recalculate the whole layout if other elements change position when you change the drawable. I don't think they wrote code to keep the layout the same    if the new drawable has the same size  as the last one, and this will involve more calculations than a simple tinting.

Answer (score 1):

color filtering is better because it use GPU( so it faster) and it can decries size of your final apk but sometime using hardware accelerator can make your application laggy and slow because of leak of memory ,size of your drawable, bad design and ...

Comment: i already use that color filtering but it sometimes does not appear so i made this topic.i'll use Glide to load different drawables maybe it won't take too big memory size.thank you for your answer! +1